# How can I display a bing map in any HTML page?

Tags: dictionary, bing-maps, dhtml

Bing's got something they call "an AJAX control" that can dynamically embed generated maps into any webpage. There's [an online interactive demo for the control](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1).

How can I use this control?

Comment: did you mean "how can i display a bing* map in any html page?" ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

Comment: FYI..... "bing" is a search engine. "Bing-Maps" is what your question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gpx5w/8/embedded/result/).

[image]

There's a Javascript class library available at
http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0

You need to include it into your page like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
```

And then call it from within javascript like this:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('SDKmap'), 
                                 {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'});
```

To get a bing maps key, go to  [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx).

You need a div with that id in your HTML page, and it should be sized and styled position:relative:

```
<div id="SDKmap" style="position:relative; height:400px; width:400px">
```

You can then add information boxes and pushpins to that map.

---

I also built a javascript helper that can extract custom attributes form the div element, and generate the map for you, complete with pushpins and infoboxes.  like this:

```
  <div id='map3'
       class='map'
       data-mapdata='center: 42.3 -78.0; zoom:7;pushpin:42.323 -78.80; pushpin:42.93 -77.189; pushpin: 41.13 -78.389'></div>
```

And then the javascript:

```
        bingMap.displayMap("map3");
```

The js module containing the helper class is available on the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 3):

The link you mentioned itself has a **View HTML** button on bottom, you can click it and grab the code to display in any webpage. Like below (which i got from your link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Map with valid credentials</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;

      function getMap()
      {
          map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'});
      }   
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With lots of JavaScript? Look on the http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ site where there is ample documentation.

There are also many other ways to embed a dynamic map in a site - take a look [GIS.stackexchange.com](http://GIS.stackexchange.com)'s [comparison of JavaScript mapping libraries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries). If you have more specific questions, we'll be happy to help over at GIS.se.